# Return Last Day of Month using Proc SQL in SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Probably a simple answer for you gurus!
I'm trying to return the last day of the month using PROC SQL in SAS
I have the following. It runs, but I do not see anything get returned.

What I really would like to do is have the End of Month Dates for the **PAST 4 Years**. It has got to be something simple but I can't figure it out !

```
PROC SQL;

 
SELECT DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM, -1, getdate()),-1) as ARS_DATE

;QUIT;
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: DATEADD isn't a valid SAS function. Use INTNX. For generating data SQL doesn't work well in this case, a data step is much more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATEADD isn't a valid SAS function AFAIK, it's an Oracle one I believe (or MS SQL?).

Use INTNX() instead. For generating a list of dates, a data step is more efficient.

```
data month_ends;

do i=1 to 48; *48 months = 4 years;
  date_end = intnx('month', today(), -1*i, 'e');
  format date_end yymmdd10.;
  output;
end;

run;
```